# ( WSGI ) Escape HTML but show HTML on the web properly.. ( as html code )

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I created a function in python:

```
def esc_ht(a):
    a = a.replace("<", "&lt;")
    a = a.replace(">", "&gt;")
    a = a.replace('"', "&quot;")
    a = a.replace("'", "&#39;")
    a = a.replace("&", "&amp;")
    return a
```

test string :

```
a = '<'
b = esc_ht(a)
```

on the web this shows as :

```
   &lt;
```

but i want it to show as.. what it is..

```
<
```

Comment: `from urllib2 import quote`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `content-type` of the response starts with `text/html`. Otherwise browser will renders the text as-as, instead of interpreting the page as html.

BTW, you case use [`cgi.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape) to HTML-escape:

```
>>> import cgi
>>> cgi.escape('<')
'&lt;'
```